# can't embed edge animate in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, adobe-edge

I've produced Adobe edge animate animation.  I am trying to use it in a Bootstrap 3 website.  However, I can't find a way to embed it that respects the row and column formatting of bootstrap when the animation is published as "Responsive Scaling"  The animation jus blows the boundaries of the columns every time.

Has anyone had success combining edge animate graphics in a bootstrap design?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem, try adding this to the javascript parameters in the header (after height & width etc):

```
bScaleToParent:"true"
```